# PhantomJs 2.1.1 Not Working on CentOs 6.5 with Selenium 3.4

Tags: java, linux, selenium, phantomjs, centos6

I am trying to run a selenium script on phantom Browser.

I did the following steps:

1) Downloaded phantomjs 2.1.1

2) Had selenium 3.4 with Phantomdriver 1.4.3 and Java 1.8.0_151

3) Ran following code:

```
File file = new File("PHANTOM_PATH");               
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());        
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.get(<Url>);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

It works fine on windows but doesn't works on CENTOS6.5. URl doesn't loads and return empty title.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the following packages made it work:

```
yum install fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++
```